# Elasticsearch Python API delete method

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm running an AWS Elasticsearch Service cluster with ES 5.5, and am trying to perform a delete document operation using the [Python API](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html).

When searching for the document using a document ID string, the API returns True.

```
doc_exists = esClient.exists(index='debug', doc_type='_all', id=doc_id)
```

However, when I try to delete it using the same document ID, I receive a NotFoundError.

```
esClient.delete(index='debug', doc_type='_all', id=doc_id)
```

exception received:

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: TransportError(404, '
{
    "found": false,
    "_index": "debug",
    "_type": "_all",
    "_id": "some-id-with-dash_and_underscore",
    "_version": 1,
    "result": "not_found",
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    }
}
'): NotFoundError
```

Can't figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: Please post all of the python code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected. You are using _all for type which in exists query will return the first doc found in any of the types in index but in delete you need to specify the exact type where the doc is present, not all types in the index.